# Vue 3 "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I am working on my first Vue 3 project after using Vue 2 for a long time.

Normally in my components on Vue 2 projects I can import a library, for example moment, like so:

```
<script>
const moment = require("moment")
export default {
  ...
</script>
```

In vue 3, I'm trying to do the same:

```
<script setup>
const moment = require("moment")
</script>
```

However I get the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

How can I get around this and import modules into a vue3 component?

Comment: even on vue2, you should use import not require

Answer (score 2):

You cann't use `require` in Vite, did you try with import:

```
<script setup>
  import moment from 'moment'
```